# Razorpay implementation error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, razorpay

**I have implemented  Razorpay-checkout,
but when I clicked build it shows only manifest error, I tried many times, but it always shows an error, I have attached some code please help me. I have seeing this type error
Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined**

**Gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.razopay"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        targetSdkVersion 31
        minSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.12'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**Build Error**

```
Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.razopay">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Razopay">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to override manifest settings of razorpay.

Add below lines in your AndroidManifest.xml file in order to override manifest settings of razorpay.

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.razorpay.RzpTokenReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="rzp.device_token.share" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<activity
    android:name="com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/RazorpayTheme"
    tools:replace="android:theme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <data
            android:host="rzp.io"
            android:scheme="io.rzp" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and We also have to replace the theme of CheckoutActivity in order to resolve further crashes,

```
tools:replace="android:theme
```

tag is important here, which has been mentioned above in manifest settings, now add below code to styles.xml.

```
 <style name="RazorpayTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. RazorPay should have this in their official documentation until there is a fix for this from Google.